# ReactJS to present the data coming from a mongodbstitch into a table

Tags: reactjs

I am getting data frm mongodb using mongodbstitcg in  a JSON format as:

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5def1f22b15556e4e9bdb345"},"Time":{"$numberDouble":"1616180000000"},"Image_Path":"1575946831220.jpg","permission":"Read:Write"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5def1f22b15556e4e9bdb346"},"Time":{"$numberDouble":"727672000000000000"},"Image_Path":"8398393839313893.jpg","permission":"Read:Write"},{"_id":{"$oid":"5def1f22b15556e4e9bdb347"},"Time":{"$numberDouble":"84983500000000"},"Image_Path":"82492849284984.jpg","permission":"Read:Write"}]
```

I have a csv File and exported that using mongodbimport and when query this is the output.
I am really getting difficult to present this a editable table.

I can see in response but that  it is failing when I am trying to render on screen?

Comment: check that i posted solution. is that you want?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting key-value pair data.

access like this

```
let data = [
{"_id":{"$oid":"5def1f22b15556e4e9bdb345"},
"Time":{"$numberDouble":"1616180000000"},
"Image_Path":"1575946831220.jpg","permission":"Read:Write"},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5def1f22b15556e4e9bdb346"},
"Time":{"$numberDouble":"727672000000000000"},
"Image_Path":"8398393839313893.jpg","permission":"Read:Write"},
{"_id":{"$oid":"5def1f22b15556e4e9bdb347"},
"Time":{"$numberDouble":"84983500000000"},
"Image_Path":"82492849284984.jpg","permission":"Read:Write"}
]

let json = Object.values(data);
```

in reactjs

```
  return (
    <div>
      {json.map(a => 
        <div key={a.id}>
          <h4>image path --{a.Image_Path}</h4>
          <h6>Permission-- {a.permission}</h6>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you this works but I am not getting like a editable table ..

Comment: @SrNew please accept/vote for this it it's helpful to you and what do you mean by editable can you explain little more so that i could help you.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Yes I will accept it. I am looking for this as a editable table. A Table wuth rows and colums that I can edit it

Comment: I am looking to represent that data in a table format that can be editable.

Comment: @SrNew can you show your requirement screenshot and what type of editable?

Comment: Its a table with - Time Path Permission as heading and all these values. anything is fine. when displayed people can edit for example chnage the permission value...

Comment: Basically, its a Table with Headings and Values. when wanted we should be able to edit any value . later when I keep a submit button . when that button is pressed only the chnaged values should go..but for now I am looking only a editable table